# Converting C# method to vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am new to vb.net and need to convert on of the C# classes to vb.net. Here is C# class

```
[Serializable]
    [XmlType(TypeName = "DomEvents")]
    public class DomEvents : System.Collections.CollectionBase
    {

        public void Add(DomEvent domEvent)
        {
            List.Add(domEvent);
        }

        public DomEvent this[int index]
        {
            get { return (DomEvent)List[index]; }
            set { List[index] = value; }
        }
    }
```

Now here is vb.net that have

```
Imports System
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

<System.Serializable()>
<XmlType(TypeName:="DomEvents")>
Public Class DomEvents
    Inherits System.Collections.CollectionBase

    Public Sub Add(ByVal domEvent As DomEvent)
        List.Add(domEvent)
    End Sub


End Class
```

How can i convert the DomEvent property to vb.net?

```
public DomEvent this[int index]
        {
            get { return (DomEvent)List[index]; }
            set { List[index] = value; }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried searching for a code converter?  First one I found seems to give you a pretty good result.

Comment: no, i was trying to learn indexer properties in vb.net

Comment: [Robot will convert code for free](http://converter.telerik.com/)

Comment: should be noted that you can directly run a referenced VB assembly from C# without any conversion. VB and C# actually compile to identical assemblies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of C#/VB converters available online. The most popular one I know is [Telerik](http://converter.telerik.com/) (hint: it's the first result when searching for "C# to VB").

It says this is the translation to VB:

```
Public Default Property Item(index As Integer) As DomEvent
    Get
        Return DirectCast(List(index), DomEvent)
    End Get
    Set
        List(index) = value
    End Set
End Property
```

As Tim quite rightly pointed out it's worth mentioning that these tools are not bullet proof by any means, but they're a good starting point. Often the code works immediately, other times it requires a little reverse engineering on your part.

Comment: Tools like this are a good start, but don't rely on them. They're good to start with, but they don't always work properly.

Comment: Oh absolutely, it was for the OP's benefit as he hadn't mentioned even trying this as a starting point.

Comment: I am going to take this as an answer. I have used this http://www.developer.com/net/vb/article.php/1471701/Defining-Default-Indexers-in-Visual-Basic.htm link to learn the indexer properties in vb.net. I have never used these converters and hopefully will never need to.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend the telerik online tool I ve seen in another answer.. 
I would suggest [Roslyn Code Converter - icsharpcode/CodeConverter](https://codeconverter.icsharpcode.net/) online (which is based

> It produced casting errors in my case

Example VB:

```
myObj.myProp = CType(someObj, SomeType).Value
```

Converted by telerik to:

```
myObj.myProp = (SomeType)someObj.Value;
```

While the correct (from icsharpcode) is:

```
myObj.myProp = ((SomeType)someObj).Value;
```